# Taking screenshots with a loop in selenium

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a loop which takes a query and returns all of the search results that are generated. The majority of the work is being done using Selenium. Every time the query is run, the page refreshes with the results. While I can get the results to display, I was wondering if there was a way to save a screenshot of the result, with the query’s name. This is what I have so far:

```
    try:
    driver.switch_to.default_content()
    driver.switch_to_frame("content_area")
    driver.switch_to_frame("list")
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('results')
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('results-con')

    html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    Hits = soup.find_all('div', class_="resultlist-entry no-ope-entry")
    for i in Hits:
        print "Query:", q, "Hit:", i.text.strip()
        savename = i + '.png'
        driver.save_screenshot(savename) 

    if not Hits:
        print "Query:", q, "@ NO HITS!!"
        savename = i + '.png'
        driver.save_screenshot(savename) 
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.back()
except:
    pass
```

The code above works for getting the query and displaying the hits, however, it does not take any screenshots? What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to take screenshots for the "i" in the loop?

Comment: So you are trying to use `BeautifulSoup` to find elements in your HTML but you can locate elements using selenium itself. Checkout [this tutorial](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) to get started.

Comment: No...that's not what I asked.

Comment: Got it. Why not specify full image path instead of just `i + ".png"` ? Like `driver.save_screenshot("/your/path/to/images/"+savename)`.

Comment: I'm guessing it's throwing an exception trying to coerce whatever `soup.find_all` returns into a string by `savename = i + '.png'` but you're not seeing that because you're `pass`ing all exceptions